# How nginx is able to access its default virtual host files when selinux is enabled?

Tags: nginx, selinux

From what I can tell, `nginx` is running in `httpd_t` security context, while `index.html`, for instance, is of `usr_t` one:

```
$ ps auxZ | grep 'nginx.*worker'
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    nginx    13734  0.0  0.2 112948  3600 ?        S    02:07   0:00 nginx: worker process

$ ls -Z /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

I'm running CentOS 7 here, if anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell:

```
$ sesearch -A -t usr_t -p read | grep 'httpd usr_t'
   allow httpd_t usr_t : file { ioctl read getattr execute execute_no_trans open } ;
   allow httpd_t usr_t : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ;
   allow httpd_t usr_t : lnk_file { read getattr } ;
```

Which supposedly means, that web servers are allowed to access `usr_t` files. Also, I'm told that `usr_t` is widely readable.